# CCRotateTo ISSUE - Xcode 4.0.2 && cocos2d-iphone-1.0.0-rc3

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

When I pass in the angle parameter 360 it doesn't execute, but if I pass in 180 it will only execute once...I have done this many times before in older versions of cocos2d. It is either I am completely missing something obvious in the code, or something with the unstable build version. Any help is appreciated.

```
    CCSprite *sun = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Sun.png"];
    sun.position = ccp(470,310);
    [self addChild:sun z:1];

    id rotateSun = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:5.0 angle:360];

    [sun runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotateSun]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
id rotateSun = [CCSequence actions:
                  [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:2.5f angle:180],
                  [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:2.5f angle:360],
                  nil];

[sun runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotateSun]];
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use

```
CCRotateBy
```

because obviously your sprite would already have the rotation set to 360 by default...